# How to create a dict from 2 dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm dealing with Python dicts now. I wrote a code:

```
import random

categories = {1 : "Antics", 2 : "Tickets", 3: "Moviez",
              4 : "Music", 5 : "Photography", 6 : "Gamez", 7 : "Bookz",
              8 : "Jewelry", 9 : "Computers", 10 : "Clothes"}

items = {"Picture" : 1, "Clock" : 1, "Ticket for Mettalica concert" : 2,
         "Ticket for Iron Maiden concert" : 2, "Ticket for Placebo concert" : 2,
         "The pianist" : 3, "Batman" : 3, "Spider-Man" : 3,
         "WoW" : 6, "Cabal" : 6, "Diablo 3" : 6, "Diablo 2" : 6,
         "Thinking in Java" : 7, "Thinking in C++" : 7, "Golden ring" : 8,
         "Asus" : 10, "HP" : 10, "Shoes" : 11}

for key, val in categories :
    for k, v in items :
        if key == v :
            print(val, k)
```

I wanted to create a 3rd dict, where i would have sth like :

```
dictThe3rd = {"Antics" : "Picture", "Antics" : "Clock", "Tickets" : "Ticket for Mettalica concert", "Ticket" : "Ticket for Iron Maiden concert", "Ticket" : "Ticket for Placebo concert", ...}
```

and so go on.

How to do this? My code shows:

> ```
> test.py, line 14, in <module>
>     for key, val in categories :
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
> ```

Comment: `dictThe3rd` is not a valid dict because it contains duplicate keys. Therefore, what you want is not possible.

Comment: is there a reason why movieZ gameZ and bookZ have a "Z"? i think its awesome. +1

Comment: Hope u arent joking :P Thanks anyway ^^

Comment: @Inbar Rose : 'cause its a 'slang' version of these words ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a dict as an iterator, it will yield only its keys, not tuples of keys and values. You would have to use `categories.items()` (or `categories.iteritems()` if you are only using Python 2.x) to get those tuples:

```
for key, val in categories.items() :
    for k, v in items.items() :
        if key == v :
            print(val, k)
```

You can use dict comprehensions to get a dict with category names as keys and all items in that category as values:

```
>>> dict3 = { catname : [ item for item, itemcat in items.items() if itemcat == cat  ] for cat, catname in categories.items()  }
>>> dict3
{'Antics': ['Picture', 'Clock'],
'Bookz': ['Thinking in C++', 'Thinking in Java'],
'Clothes': ['Asus', 'HP'],
'Computers': [],
'Gamez': ['Diablo 3', 'Diablo 2', 'Cabal', 'WoW'],
'Jewelry': ['Golden ring'],
'Moviez': ['The pianist', 'Batman', 'Spider-Man'],
'Music': [],
'Photography': [],
'Tickets': ['Ticket for Mettalica concert',
'Ticket for Placebo concert',
'Ticket for Iron Maiden concert']}
```

Explanation:

The inner comprehension in square brackets will list all items that have a category of `cat`. The outer comprehension will iterate over all category keys and names, setting the category name as the new dict key and the inner comprehension as a value.

Comment: nice, but how to build a dict from it? In dict there's no chance to have two (or more) same keys ...

Comment: I think that if you iterate over a dict it yields its keys not its values.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
for key, val in categories.iteritems():
    for k, v in items.iteritems():
        if key == v:
            print(val, k)
```

This way you can iterate over key/value pairs using an itemiterator which yields better performance than `items()` for large dictionaries.

What you want is possible like this:

```
import collections
dictThe3rd=collections.defaultdict(set)
for key, val in categories.iteritems():
    for k, v in items.iteritems():
        if key == v:
            dictThe3rd[val].add(k)
print dictThe3rd
```

which yields

```
{'Tickets': set(['Ticket for Mettalica concert', 'Ticket for Placebo concert',
    'Ticket for Iron Maiden concert']),
'Jewelry': set(['Golden ring']),
'Antics': set(['Picture', 'Clock']),
'Moviez': set(['Batman', 'Spider-Man', 'The pianist']),
'Bookz': set(['Thinking in Java', 'Thinking in C++']),
'Gamez': set(['Diablo 3', 'Diablo 2', 'WoW', 'Cabal']),
'Clothes': set(['Asus', 'HP'])}
```

Comment: Use a `defaultdict(set)` for dictThe3rd instead, and you won't have to use that archaic and clunky setdefault call (which creates a throwaway set() for every call, whether needed or not), instead just writing `dictThe3rd[val].add(k)` and let the defaultdict class take care of creating the initial set when val is a not-seen-before key.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `items()` as in Stefan solution, but if you want to construct new dictionary instead of printing create list or append to it:

```
dictThe3rd = {}
for key, val in categories.items():
    for k, v in items.items():
        if key == v :
            #print(val, k)
            try:
                dictThe3rd[val].append(k)
            except KeyError:
                dictThe3rd[val] = [k]

print(dictThe3rd)
```